# Android SDK content loader has encountered an error

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

So i use eclipse ADT at ubuntu and i am getting the following error when i start eclipse:

'Android SDK content Loader' has encountered a problem
parseSDKcontentfailed

parseSdkContent failed
java.lang.NullPointerException

At the same time the Android SDK Manager refuses to open (loads up properly but never opens) and every time i try to open the Android Virtual Device MAnager i get the error
 'location of android SDK has not been set up in preferances'
even though i have actually set this up through the windows>preferance>android window

[img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFxTf.png

Can someone please give me some insight here? I have searched solutions for the above problems but every one of them requires on of the components (SDK MAnager/virtual device manager) and i cant use any of em.

I am not an expert or anything at using eclipse, in fact i am at my first steps, so please any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so i managed to fix this by deleting the AVD folder inside the .android folder on my home directory.